# Use another function to create objects

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to Java, and I was making a small application that takes two cars and returns who is faster. I made another class for the cars. First I made all the objects in the main method and it worked, then I tried putting the code in another method and called that from main, just to make it neater, and I got an error. Probably something obvious, but I'm too tired to think straight.

Error:(7, 14) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable ferrari
  location: class Test

Error:(7, 23) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable lamborghini
  location: class Test

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    createCars();

    race(ferrari, lamborghini);

}

public static void createCars() {

    Car ferrari = new Car("Ferrari", "California");
    ferrari.setHp(552);
    ferrari.setAcceleration(3.3);

    Car lamborghini = new Car("Lamborghini", "Huracan");
    lamborghini.setHp(602);
    lamborghini.setAcceleration(2.5);

    Car bmw = new Car("BMW", "M5");
    bmw.setHp(560);
    bmw.setAcceleration(3.7);

    Car cadillac = new Car("Cadillac", "CTS-V");
    cadillac.setHp(640);
    cadillac.setAcceleration(3.6);

}


public static void race(Car carA, Car carB) {
    if (carA.getAcceleration() < carB.getAcceleration()) {
        System.out.println("The " + carA.getMake() + " " + carA.getModel() + " is faster than the " + carB.getMake() + " " + carB.getModel());
    } else if (carB.getAcceleration() < carA.getAcceleration()) {
        System.out.println("The " + carB.getMake() + " " + carB.getModel() + " is faster than the " + carA.getMake() + " " + carA.getModel());
    } else {
        System.out.println("It's a tie");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Once you leave the `createCars` method, the variables defined within that method are gone.  You either need to return them from the method or use class-level variables.

Comment: You create the objects in the createCars method but they can only be seen by this method. When the method ends the ferrari and lamborghini are gone.

Comment: Knew it was something that easy, haha! Thanks guys, would probably have been stuck forever on such a stupid thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get that error because your car instances `ferrari` and `lamborghini` are not in the scope of the main function.

You may modify your create cars method to it returns a new car insteand:

```
public static Car createCar(String make, String model, int hp, double acceleration ) {
  Car car = new Car(make, model);
  car.setHp(hp);
  car.setAcceleration(acceleration);
  return car;
}
```

and then you can use it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Car ferrari = createCar("Ferrari", "California", 552, 3.3 );
    Car lamborghini = createCar("Lamborghini", "Huracan", 602, 2.5 );
    race(ferrari, lamborghini);

}
```

... or directly

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    race( 
        createCar("Ferrari", "California", 552, 3.3 ),
        createCar("Lamborghini", "Huracan", 602, 2.5 )
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, nice and easy!

Comment: @EmilØgård Isn't that what you've started with, when you created all your objects in the `main()` method?

Comment: @EmilØgård  additionally, this way doesn't directly support the creation of multiple ( > 2 ) cars.

Answer (score 3):

Declare your objects ahead of time. This allows the variables to remain in scope for your `race()` function. Otherwise, only the `createCars()` method sees your Cars.

```
public class Test {

    static Car ferrari;
    static Car lamborghini;
    static Car bmw;
    static Car cadillac;

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        createCars();    
        race(ferrari, lamborghini);    
    }

    public static void createCars() {

        ferrari = new Car("Ferrari", "California");
        ferrari.setHp(552);
        ferrari.setAcceleration(3.3);

        lamborghini = new Car("Lamborghini", "Huracan");
        lamborghini.setHp(602);
        lamborghini.setAcceleration(2.5);

        bmw = new Car("BMW", "M5");
        bmw.setHp(560);
        bmw.setAcceleration(3.7);

        cadillac = new Car("Cadillac", "CTS-V");
        cadillac.setHp(640);
        cadillac.setAcceleration(3.6);

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any easy way to make this work without creating the objects in the class? So I didn't need to declare it every time I'm going to make another Car object?

Comment: Well, you could create an `ArrayList` to store your Car objects, and only globally instantiate that. Then within your `createCars()` method you'd add any new Objects to that array and which would persist throughout runtime.

Comment: Thanks, helped me a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The objects that you create become unreachable (and therefore ready for garbage collection) as soon as the method in which you created them is over. This is because you assign them to *local variables* inside that method, and no other part of your program has access to these variables.

You need a way for the rest of your program to access the cars you created. One way is to make an object that "holds" them, like this:

```
class Garage {
    private Car ferrari;
    private Car lamborghini;
    private Car bmw;
    private Car cadillac;
    // You could use a constructor instead of using a separate method.
    public void createCars() {
        ferrari = new Car("Ferrari", "California");
        ferrari.setHp(552);
        ferrari.setAcceleration(3.3);

        lamborghini = new Car("Lamborghini", "Huracan");
        lamborghini.setHp(602);
        lamborghini.setAcceleration(2.5);

        bmw = new Car("BMW", "M5");
        bmw.setHp(560);
        bmw.setAcceleration(3.7);

        cadillac = new Car("Cadillac", "CTS-V");
        cadillac.setHp(640);
        cadillac.setAcceleration(3.6);
    }
    public void getFerrari() {return ferrari;}
    public void getLamborghini() {return lamborghini;}
    public void getBmw() {return bmw;}
    public void getCadillac() {return cadillac;}
}
```

Now you can use the `Garage` class in your `main()` method, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Garage garage = new Garage();
    // If you move createCars into Garage's constructor, you wouldn't need to call createCars any longer.
    garage.createCars();

    race(garage.getFerrari(), garage.GetLamborghini());
}
```